# error: module xport has no attribute XportReader, python xport file reader

Tags: module, attributeerror

I am importing a module for reading SAS xport files in my main python script. The imported module is called xport.py and has a class XportReader. When I run my original python script it gives an error module xport has no attribute XportReader. I am new to python. Though XportReader is a class why interpreter is considering it as attribute? Any help is much appreciated.

I am executing in Kaggle and My code is like this:

```py
import xport
FN = ['ABC.XPT','xyz.XPT']
def get_data(fname)
 with xport.XportReader(fname) as reader:
  ....
#Read data files
for fn in FN:
  fn1=os.path.join("../Data/",fn) 
  X=get_data(fn1)
  ....
```

I have imported data files and xport module is set as utility script.

```py
xport module format-
from datetime import datetime
import struct
..
```

Methods...

```py
class XportReader(object):
  def __init__(..)
  ....
if __name__ = "__main__":
   import sys
   with XportReader(sys.argv[1]) as reader:
     for obj in reader:
       print obj***
```

Please help. I am using xport.py module for reading NHANES XPT files to obtain raw binary data in pandas dataframe format.

Comment: Try using Pandas :
1. import pandas as pd
2. df = pd.read_sas('ABC.XPT')

This should load data in the pandas dataframe form